# Changing from ROA to British Citizenship

Tags: united-kingdom

I have been living in the UK since 1st July 1976 with an ancestor ROA visa. On 13th July 1978 I married my British husband and continued with ROA visa and now I feel I would like to become a British citizen. I feel more Brit than Aussie. How do I go about it?

Answer (score 1):

You can [check whether you are eligible to become a British citizen online](https://www.gov.uk/british-citizenship).

You can also [apply for naturalization online](https://visas-immigration.service.gov.uk/product/nationality-an).  It's expensive.  The fee is currently £1330, plus a biometric fee of £19.20.  If you don't have a [certificate of entitlement](https://www.gov.uk/right-of-abode/apply-for-a-certificate-of-entitlement) of your right of abode, you'll need to pay another £372 for that.

Comment: Would the OP benefit from (the side effect of) the [Windrush Scheme](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/windrush-scheme)? While it is not intended for OP's case and cost a lot of taxpayers' money, the way the scheme was constructed has [enticed a number of its non-target audience in successfully applying](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-49569137).

Comment: @B.Liu The scheme would indeed appear to allow her to get documentation of her right of abode free of charge, if she has no such documentation, so thanks for pointing that out.  The page you link to says "you may also be able to apply for British citizenship for free," but I didn't see any mention of this in the pages that it links to.  The [guidance](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/807365/windrush-scheme-casework-guidance-v3.0-ext.pdf) seems to say that one requirement for this is having arrived under the age of 18.